# Comparação de horas MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, time

Tenho uma agenda onde cadastro um compromisso, esse compromisso tem `Hora Inicial` e `Hora Final`. Porem agora quando eu cadastrar um novo compromisso tenho que fazer uma verificação pra ver se as horas não estão entre as horas já cadastradas. Exemplo:

Tenho um compromisso com Hora Inicial `13:00` e Hora Final: `14:00` Na data de hoje. Como verifico esse período de tempo para não deixar que nada seja cadastrado nesse intervalo das `13:00` as `14:00`?

Comment: Você precisa fazer isso via MYsql ou via java?

Comment: preciso fazer Mysql passando duas horas como parâmetro.

Comment: Eu pensei em fazer da seguinte forma: Sempre que eu for salvar um compromisso eu faço uma consulta no banco passando duas horas como parâmetro, hora inicial e hora final. Dai no banco eu faço uma verificação pra ver se as horas passadas como parâmetro estão dentro do período de algum compromisso já salvo. Porém não sei se é possível fazer isso no banco rsrs

Comment: Como falei na outra pergunta to muito sem tempo esses dias, você pode fazer algo com o comando `BETWEEN` do mysql  onde você testa algo durante um intervalo que no caso seria entre 13 e 14. Caso nao consiga nada em casa posto um exemplo,

Comment: Vou tentar usar o BETWEEN, obrigado por mandar a dica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para localizar registos entre duas datas em MySQL, podes fazer uso da função [`BETWEEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between).

Se for uma coluna do tipo [`datetime`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `minhaTabela`
WHERE `campoDatetime` BETWEEN '2015-07-10 13:00:00' AND '2015-07-10 14:00:00';
```

Se for uma coluna do tipo [`time`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `minhaTabela`
WHERE `campoTime` BETWEEN '13:00:00' AND '14:00:00';
```

Se a consulta devolver 1 ou mais resultados, então sabes que já existem compromissos.

Comment: Opa funcionou certinho, fiz da seguinte forma:`SELECT * FROM db_agenda.tbl_compromissos Where '15:00' BETWEEN hora_inicio And hora_fim`. Agora uma ultima dúvida, como faço pra passar um parâmetro no lugar desse `15:00` no código java?

Comment: Eu tendei de uma maneira que não deu muito certo:
`tabela = consulta.executeQuery("SELECT cod_compromisso, nome_beneficiario, compromisso FROM tbl_compromissos Where hora_inicio='"+horaInicio+"' BETWEEN hora_inicio And hora_fim");`

Comment: Opa, ja consegui aqui também. Obrigado

Comment: Esse `15:00` está vindo como parametro? se estiver pode passar por exemplo `psmt.setDate(1, agenda.getHorarioEscolhido());`, onde o número 1 indica o primeiro parametro